# Проблема с выводом из словаря Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, print, visual-studio-2022

Решил сделать простенькую программу для просмотра характеристик разных машин в формате "модельМашины.информацияОМашине" в Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 на Python, а IDE пишет ошибку, якобы в функции print неправильные аргументы. Хотел бы узнать как вывести именно то что я хочу(то есть вводишь к примеру "skodaFabia2011.body", и программа выводит "Wagon"). Скриншот ошибки приложу.
[image: Вот сама ошибка]
[image: А в самой IDE до запуска ошибок он не находит]
Вот код программы:

```py
chooseCar = input()
carModel = "";
typeOfCar = "";
for i in chooseCar:
    if i != ".":
        carModel += i;
    else:
        break
typeOfCar = chooseCar.replace(carModel, "", 1)
typeOfCar = typeOfCar.replace(".", "", 1)
carsList = {
    'skodaFabia2011': { #Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011
        'fullName': "Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011",
        'year': "2011",
        'countryOfAssembly': "Czech",
        'body': "Wagon",
        'doorsAndSeats': "5/5",
        'weight': "1090",
        'fullWeight': "1605",
        'maximumSpeedReal': "165kmh",
        'maximumSpeedSpec': "192kmh",
        'acellerate': "0-100kmh - 10.5s",
        'trunkCapacityMin': "505L",
        'trunkCapacityMax': "1485L",
        'length': "4247mm",
        'width': "1642mm",
        'height': "1498mm",
        'wheelbase': "2451mm",
        'trackFront': "1433mm",
        'trackBack': "1426mm",
        'clearance': "149mm",
        'typeOfFuel': "Petrol 92-95",
        'locationOfEngine': "Front, transverse",
        'litersOfEngine': "1598cm",
        'compressionRatio': "10.5",
        'enginePowerSystem': "Distributed Inject",
        'cylinders': "4",
        'valves': "16",
        'horsePower': "105hp",
        'torque': "153nm",
        'torqueAtRPM': "153nm/3800rpm",
        'transmissionType': "Manual 5-Speed",
        'driveWheels': "FWD",
        'suspensionFront': "Independent, spring-loaded",
        'suspensionRear': "Semi-independent, spring-loaded",
        'tireSize': "195/55",
        'diskSize': "R15",
        'brakesFront': "Ventilated disc",
        'brakesRear': "Drum",
        'fuelConsumptionUrban': "9.1L - 100km",
        'fuelConsumptionSuburban': "5.6L - 100km",
        'fuelConsumptionMixed': "6.9L - 100km",
        'octaneOfFuel': "Minimum: AI-92, Recommended: AI-95",
        'fuelTankCapacity': "45L",
        } #Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011
    }
print(carsList(carModel(typeOfCar)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как пример

```
carsList['skodaFabia2011']['body']
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде как помогло. Я пробовал также, только с круглыми скобками.

Comment: Еще раз перечитайте главу о словарях в Пайтоне для закрепления.